# Django login FieldError - Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'request' into field

Tags: django, mezzanine

I've setup Django + Mezzanine on in a localhost virtual environment.

On the admin login page, I input my admin username and password and am returned with a Traceback that I do not understand.

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('mezzanine.boot',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'mezzanine.conf',
 'mezzanine.core',
 'mezzanine.generic',
 'mezzanine.pages',
 'mezzanine.blog',
 'mezzanine.forms',
 'mezzanine.galleries',
 'mezzanine.twitter',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_comments')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware')
```

Traceback:

```
File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  178.             response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\middleware.py" in process_view
  39.             response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  393.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  182.         if form.is_valid():

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  385.         self._clean_form()

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  412.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in clean
  187.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\auth_backends.py" in authenticate
  34.                     user = User.objects.get(username_or_email, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  371.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  784.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  802.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1261.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1165.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1045.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

File "c:\projects\1111\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1363.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'request' into field. Choices are: blogposts, comment_comments, comment_flags, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, ratings, sitepermissions, user_permissions, username
```

Are my admin username and password credentials incorrect?
Or is there another problem going on?

Comment: Where is your custom code that you wrote?

Comment: @latsha, I didn't write any custom code. There is a Mezzanine CMS module that contains code to customize Django.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed the Mezzanine development version to support Django (1.11.2). Solution: install the dev version of Mezzanine from https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine